# Typical LANs with VLANs

Tags: vlan

When using switches which support VLANs with switches which doesn't support VLANs, can they be mixed with each other in the same network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix VLAN switches and non-VLAN switches in a network under the premise that none of the non-VLAN switches ever sees a tagged frame (which it doesn't understand).

For instance you could have VLAN switches and trunks in the network cener and use non-VLAN access switches where there's only a single VLAN to be serviced.

You'd configure the downlink from core/distribution with a single, untagged VLAN, of course. If you actually configured a VLAN trunk towards a non-VLAN switch, anyone connected to that switch could hop onto any VLAN simply by tagging frames. (With an 802.1D-compliant switch, tagged frames would be dropped, but practically all dumb switches actually forward them instead.)

Comment: "does not support" does not always mean "does not understand".

Answer (score 3):

As Zac67 has already said, if you don't send tagged frames to those switches, they'll happily go about the job of switching traffic.

*However*, if you send tagged traffic to a switch that hasn't been configured for it, anything can happen. "*Does not support*" does not always mean "*does not understand*". There are a lot of unmanaged switches built using hardware that knows what 802.1q is. The fact that they're unmanaged means you can't tell them what to do with those frames. In the best case, they drop those frames. In the *worst* case, they remove the tag and process the frame anyway. (in the even worse case, the switch crashes, but I've only seen one switch did that.)

A "dumb" switch that has no knowledge of 802.1q will see the frame just like any other frame. It doesn't care what the ethernet protocol number may be. (8100 for dot1q, 86dd for IPv6, etc.) 802.1q adds 4 bytes to the frame, so it *might* end up being too big, at which point it would be dropped. (unless it was configured for jumbo frame, and if it can odds are it understands and supports VLANs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no issue in mixing managed and unmanaged switch in setup . In mànage switch we will have feasibility to create , delete ,modify VLANs on managed switch . Where as in unmanaged switch it is  not feasible to create , VLANs . However we can connect both switch to establish connectivity in setup .

But mixing managed and unmanaged switch is not a good practices . Unmanaged switch is not capable for runing Spaning tree protocols STP .Any kind  of loop avoidance machanism is not possible in umanaged switch hence high possibility of looping accour in network . Further impact entire networks .